# Class button timeout

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i have a class that has some functions that are making a carousel work. But pressing the next button fast deletes the previous animation and starts the next so i want to make the button wait for the animation to end. The animation inside css is 0.6 seconds but the timeous i set inside goNext functions is completely ignored when i fast click the button. What am I doing wrong here?
index.js

```
let carousel = document.getElementById("carousel");
let seats = document.querySelectorAll("ul > li");

if (seats.length === 1)
  carousel.style.left = 0;

class SLID {
  constructor() {
    this.nextDisable = true;
    this.changeNextDisable = this.changeNextDisable.bind(this);
  }

  changeNextDisable() {
    this.nextDisable = false;
  }

  goToNext() {
   if(this.nextDisable===false){
    this.nextDisable = true;
    var el, i, j, new_seat, ref;
    el = document.querySelector("ul > li.is-ref");
    el.classList.remove('is-ref');
    new_seat = el.nextElementSibling || seats[0];
    new_seat.classList.add('is-ref');
    new_seat.style.order = 1;
    for (i = j = 2, ref = seats.length; (2 <= ref ? j <= ref : j >= ref); i = 2 <= ref ? ++j : --j) {
      new_seat = new_seat.nextElementSibling || seats[0];
      new_seat.style.order = i;
    }
    carousel.classList.remove('toPrev');
    carousel.classList.add('toNext');
    carousel.classList.remove('is-set');
    return setTimeout(()=> {
        this.changeNextDisable();
        carousel.classList.add('is-set');
    }, 60);
  }

  goToPrev() {
    var el, i, j, new_seat, ref;
    el = document.querySelector("ul > li.is-ref");
    el.classList.remove('is-ref');
    new_seat = el.previousElementSibling || seats[seats.length - 1];
    new_seat.classList.add('is-ref');
    new_seat.style.order = 1;
    for (i = j = 2, ref = seats.length; (2 <= ref ? j <= ref : j >= ref); i = 2 <= ref ? ++j : --j) {
      new_seat = new_seat.nextElementSibling || seats[0];
      new_seat.style.order = i;
    }
    carousel.classList.remove('toNext');
    carousel.classList.add('toPrev');
    carousel.classList.remove('is-set');
    return setTimeout((function () {
      return carousel.classList.add('is-set');
    }), 50);
  }
}
}
let s = new SLID();

document.getElementById("nextButton").addEventListener("click", () => {
  s.goToNext();
});

document.getElementById("prevButton").addEventListener("click", () => {
  s.goToPrev();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your animation type (`transition` or `animation`) you can replace

```
return setTimeout(()=> {
    this.changeNextDisable();
    carousel.classList.add('is-set');
}, 60);
```

(and trying avoid it) to:

```js
carousel.addEventListener("animationend", () => {
    this.changeNextDisable();
    carousel.classList.add('is-set');
}, {
    once: true,
});
```

or

```js
carousel.addEventListener("transitionend", () => {
    this.changeNextDisable();
    carousel.classList.add('is-set');
}, {
    once: true,
});
```

same thing for `goToPrev` method.

Comment: It will work only for element that contains css animation. If `carousel` element have no animation but some of its children have then instead of `carousel.addEventListener` you need to use `otherElement.addEventListener`.

Answer (score 0):

You tell us that the CSS animation has a duration of 0.6 seconds, which is 600 milliseconds, not 60 or 50 milliseconds, which is what you set your `setTimeout` delay to.

So:

```
return setTimeout(()=> {
    this.changeNextDisable();
    carousel.classList.add('is-set');
}, 600);
// ^^^^
```

Having said that, you should look into listening to the [`transactionend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) event, as then you don't need to know how long the CSS transition takes.

That would look like this:

```
const done = () => {
    carousel.removeEventListener("transactionend", done);
    this.changeNextDisable();
    carousel.classList.add('is-set');
}
return carousel.addEventListener("transactionend", done);
```